# Unclickable Row for React-Data-Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how I can make my react-data-grid row unclickable. So that it would look like the grid is locked from being clicked.

The definition of the data grid is below.I am using react data grid library.

```
export class DataGrid extends React.Component<IProps, IState> 
{
    columns: any[];
    constructor(props: IProps, context:any) {
        super(props, context);
        this.columns = this.props.columns;

        this.state = { selectedIndexes:[], rows: this.props.rows || [], 
filters: {}, sortColumn: null, sortDirection: null, columns: 
this.props.columns, reorderedColumns: [], emptyColumns: [] };
    }

    getRows = (): any => {

        if (this.props.rows) {
            return Data.Selectors.getRows({ ...this.state, rows: [...this.props.rows] });
        } else {
            return Data.Selectors.getRows({ ...this.state, rows: [] });
        }

    };

    getSize = () => {
        return this.getRows().length;
    };

    rowGetter = (rowIdx: any) => {
        const rows = this.getRows();
        return rows[rowIdx];
    };

    handleGridSort = (sortColumn: any, sortDirection: any) => {
        this.setState({ sortColumn: sortColumn, sortDirection: sortDirection });
    };

    handleFilterChange = (filter: any) => {
        let newFilters = {...this.state.filters};
        if (filter.filterTerm) {
            newFilters[filter.column.key] = filter;
        } else {
            delete newFilters[filter.column.key];
        }

        this.setState({ filters: newFilters });
    };

    onClearFilters = () => {
        this.setState({ filters: {} });
    };

    onHeaderDrop = (source: any, target: any) => {    
        const newstate: any = { ...this.state };    
        let columnSourceIndex:any;
        for (let i in this.state.columns) {
            if (this.state.columns[i].key === source) {
                columnSourceIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }    
        let columnTargetIndex: any;
        for (let i in this.state.columns) {
            if (this.state.columns[i].key === target) {
                columnTargetIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        newstate.columns.splice(
            columnTargetIndex,
            0,
            newstate.columns.splice(columnSourceIndex, 1)[0]
        );

        const emptyColumns = {...this.state, columns: [] as any };
        this.setState(
            emptyColumns
        );

        const reorderedColumns = { ...this.state, columns: [...stateCopy.columns] };
        console.log(reorderedColumns);
        this.setState(
            reorderedColumns
        );
    };
    currentIdx: number;
    onRowsSelected = (rows: any[]) => {
        this.setState({ selectedIndexes: this.state.selectedIndexes.concat(rows.map(r => r.rowIdx)) });
        this.props.onRowClick(rows[0].rowIdx, rows[0].row);
        this.currentIdx = rows[0].rowIdx;
    };

    onRowsDeselected = (rows: any[]) => {
        let rowIndexes = rows.map(r => r.rowIdx);
        this.setState({ selectedIndexes: this.state.selectedIndexes.filter(i => rowIndexes.indexOf(i) === -1) });
    };

    onRowClick = (idx: number, row: any) => {
        if (typeof idx != "undefined" && typeof row != "undefined") {
            this.props.onRowClick(idx, row);
        }
    }   
    render() {
        return (
            <ErrorBoundary errorMessage="Error Displaying Default grid, please check console to view error details">
                <DraggableContainer onHeaderDrop={this.onHeaderDrop}>
                    <ReactDataGrid
                        onGridSort={this.handleGridSort}
                        enableCellSelect={true}
                        columns={this.state.columns}
                        rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
                        rowsCount={this.getSize()}
                        minHeight={500}
                        onRowClick={this.onRowClick.bind(this)}
                        toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter={true} />}
                        onAddFilter={this.handleFilterChange}
                        onClearFilters={this.onClearFilters}

                        />
                </DraggableContainer>
            </ErrorBoundary>);
    }
}
```

I have definition for onRowClick and the etc. I was wondering if i can do it in the render or I have to write a function to prevent that.

Comment: what if you remove onRowClick={this.onRowClick.bind(this)}, set enableCellSelect={false} and you add pointer-events: none; to the CSS class?

Comment: I abandoned using this library for my project a while back, but when I was working on it the CustomCellFormatter example might do what you want. You could render a locked vs. unlocked look for each cell in said row.

Comment: @Sidonai,i think I will try your suggestion